# htaccess wildcard problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix

I have recently migrated my site from Expression Engine to WordPress and I'm getting a lot of 404's from the old EE paginated pages. I know I can't catch them all but if I could just get the categories to redirect to the main category pages by stripping the pagination code that would be a start here is the old offending URL structure:

```
/category/crazy-guitar-designs/P108
```

which I would like to permanently redirect to just

```
/category/crazy-guitar-designs/
```

Is this possible with wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `RedirectMatch` directive of `mod_alias`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/crazy-guitar-designs/P[0-9]+ http://www.example.com/category/crazy-guitar-designs/
```

`.+` is a *Regular Expression* for "one or more chars".

Comment: Ah hang on though, can it just be for anything starting with P and then a number? I still need the new pagination links to work like this: /category/crazy-guitar-designs/page/2/